# Include file inside foreach loop

Tags: php, foreach, include

Is it not possible to use a PHP include inside a foreach loop?

I have an array of filenames called `$posts`:

```
Array ( [3] => post-an-example-post.html
        [4] => post-my-first-test-post.html
        [5] => post-my-second-test-post.html )
```

And I want to output the contents of each of these (which is some simple HTML) for each item in the array:

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
    $post = "/posts/" . $post;
    echo $post;
    include $post;
}
```

This gives me an error for each one, as it won't use the beginning `/` I have added and instead stays within the same file?:

```
Warning: include(/posts/post-an-example-post.html): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/quick-blog/showposts.php on line 7
```

The files are all stored in /posts/ directory.

Edit: here is how the array $posts is created. It scans the directory and removes anything that doesn't start with `posts-`

```
function postArray(){
$dir    = 'posts';
$files = scandir($dir);

$posts = array_filter(
    $files,
    function($value) {
        return (strpos($value, 'post-') === 0);
    }
);
return $posts;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are giving an absolute location to `include`. It is looking for a directory called `posts` at the top of your filesystem, not the document root.

Comment: Thanks! I was being stupid.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, I often scan a given folder for files and loop through and include each. Looks like your array to me?

Should it not be strings? You could also do file_exists to :)

```
Array ( [3] => "post-an-example-post.html"
        [4] => "post-my-first-test-post.html"
        [5] => "post-my-second-test-post.html"
```

)

Comment: How would I make the array strings?

Comment: See I have added the quotation marks around the file names :) Could you post your whole code?

Comment: Hi, my array is not generated that way though, I've added the function for creating the array.

Comment: Ah it's the first forward slash here: $post = "/posts/"

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you do foreach ($posts as $post) on array given the post will be the keys of array. The array must be like that:

```
$posts = Array ( 3 => "post-an-example-post.html",
    4 => "post-my-first-test-post.html",
    5 => "post-my-second-test-post.html", 
);
```

Try now with this array